# Count freq of word and which column it appears in using R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a dataset of a series of names in different columns. Each column determines the time in which the names were entered into the system. Is it possible to find the number of times ALL the names appear and the most recent column entry. I added a picture to show how the dataset works.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: What does "most recent" mean in this context? Is the first column *"1 second ago"* and therefore the most recent, or is it the first time-unit therefore the least recent?

Comment: You said "Each column determines the time in which the names were entered into the system.", this would add problems for making tidy data. I understand this is an example question, but the columns could be fundamentally better for better and easier analysis

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method:

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
dat <- setNames(as.data.frame(replicate(4, sample(letters, size = 10, replace = TRUE))), 1:4)
dat
#    1 2 3 4
# 1  q x c c
# 2  e g i z
# 3  a d y a
# 4  y y d j
# 5  j e e x
# 6  d n m k
# 7  r t e o
# 8  z z t v
# 9  q r b z
# 10 o o h h
```

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(dat, everything(), names_to = "colname", values_to = "word") %>%
  mutate(colname = as.integer(colname)) %>%
  group_by(word) %>%
  summarize(n = n(), latest = max(colname), .groups = "drop")
# # A tibble: 20 x 3
#    word      n latest
#    <chr> <int>  <int>
#  1 a         2      4
#  2 b         1      3
#  3 c         2      4
#  4 d         3      3
#  5 e         4      3
#  6 g         1      2
#  7 h         2      4
#  8 i         1      3
#  9 j         2      4
# 10 k         1      4
# 11 m         1      3
# 12 n         1      2
# 13 o         3      4
# 14 q         2      1
# 15 r         2      2
# 16 t         2      3
# 17 v         1      4
# 18 x         2      4
# 19 y         3      3
# 20 z         4      4
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
melt(as.data.table(dat), integer(0), variable.name = "colname", value.name = "word")[
  , colname := as.integer(colname)
    ][, .(n = .N, latest = max(colname)), by = .(word) ]
```

(though it is not sorted by `word`, the values are the same)

Comment: That data.table example seems very complex. do you use data.table a lot?

Comment: Every day. Its "complexity" is likely due to `data.table`'s inherent compact nomenclature, though each of the components is precisely the same as the `dplyr` version.

Comment: Does this answer your question?